# Cannot install react-paypal-button with react 18

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, react-18

I'm following an e-commerce tutorial, cannot install all the packages react-paypal button in npm with react 18

```
npm i react-paypal-smart-button
```

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.  
    
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-09T15_12_52_013Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

react-paypal-smart-button has peerDeps like that:

```js
"peerDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
```

And you installed react version 18.
So just use flag npm i--legacy-peer-deps to ignore that warning. (then react-paypal-smart-button will use your react 18 instead of recommended 17. Hope that will not break the package:))

About peerDeps - https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/